# example.com:8080/wordpress = my website | example.com = page could not be found

Tags: html, wordpress, apache, virtualhost, bitnami

I am running lampstack with bitnami wordpress on ubuntu at my home.

```
my website = "example.com"
my ip address = "12.123.123.123
my home server's ip address = 192.168.0.101
```

basically when I go to my example.com:8080/wordpress I get my website, when I go to example.com I get a page could not be found.

my domain registrar www & @ A records point to my home server IP.

So I can get to my website by entering either `example.com:8080/wordpress` or `12.123.123.123:8080/wordpress`

In my router, I set a port range

`Application: HTTP | Start: 80 | End: 8080 | Protocol: Both | IP Address 192.168.0.101 |     Enable [YES]`

How can I get `example.com` to go to `example.com:8080/wordpress`?

Here is what my httpd-vhosts.conf file looks like in `/home/lampstack-5.3.16-0/apache2/conf/extra`

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/admins/lampstack-5.3.16-0/apps/wordpress
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot /home/admins/lampstack-5.3.16-0/apps/wordpress
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to set your documentroot (in your .conf file) to the correct wordpress directory. This is where ever wordpress/index.php resides on your hard drive.

Comment: I just updated my post to show how my httpd-vhosts.conf file looks like.

Comment: Dumb question: is there a index.php file in `/home/lampstack-5.3.16-0/apps/wordpress`?

Comment: No, but there is one in /home/lampstack-5.3.16-0/apps/wordpress/htdocs

Comment: Also, another post said that I should change listen 8080 to listen 80 in the httpd.conf file. I did that and restarted apache (the changes wouldn't come into effect before I restarted apache). Now I can't even access example.com:8080/wordpress             I am going to try to revert the changes.

Comment: Ok so I basically found out that if I don't port forward port 80 to port 8080, if I go to example.com it will go to my router page, and when I forward the port, it gets me to a page not found page. I checked if my ip address is pointing to my domain is pointing to my server and it is. But I don't need to use my domain, even if I use my external ip address, it still yields the same results.

Comment: It seems like you need some help understanding how vhosts work with apache2's conf files. Here is some great documentation: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/apache-virtual-host/